# Keykloack docker enable preview features

Tags: docker, keycloak

I'm trying to enable preview features locally in my docker container and it doesn't work. What I missed here?

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dkeycloak.profile=preview" quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.1 start-dev
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add `start-dev --features=preview` as your command, as per the [Feature Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/features). `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND` is for adding options to the JVM, rather than Keycloak itself